# Best way to distribute Android builds through a private channel

Tags: android, testing, build, server, repository

My app is now in the alpha status and I would like to distribute it to a few people (QA, alpha testers...) without making the app public. I know, that google play offers a private channel to distribute apps in alpha/beta state to some people, but according to the website it takes a few hours until the application is available. However, I would like to have it available for users as soon as a new build is ready and uploaded. I thought about setting up a private android repository (e.q f-droid), but unfortunately I could not find anything in the documentation about securing the android repository - I want it to be protected somehow (key, password...).

Another possibility would be to set up a web-server and host the different build versions on that server. Then the testers have to navigate to that site and download the appropriate build version. However, from the usability point of view it isn't that nice - user have to download the version manually and install it afterwards. Also for the QA guys it would be nicer, if it is easier to switch between different android builds.

How would you solve this problem? Is there already any software out there, that is suitable for that task?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/). Crashlytics is now integrated in [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/).

Crashlytics allows you to distrubute beta versions of your app. Testers only have to install the install the Crashlytics app, and enable installing apps from different sources. You specify which users can test the app by emailadress.

The app allows testers to switch between any version of your app, and install any possible other apps they are invited for.

You can also integrate Crashlytics in your app. If you do you get notified of errors that occured complete with stacktraces, and additional information about the device. This makes bugfixing easier.

Comment: Thanks for the Crashlytics tipp. Unfourtunately I couldn't get it to work with Qt, but with Crashlytics as a keyword, I found an alternative, that suits my needs. I am now using HockeyApp, which works pretty well for me. As you helped me finding HockeyApp, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am glad you found my answers helpfull, although it was indirect ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know Google says it can take a few hours, in my experience, it happens very quickly, a few minutes at most. I don't know if there are times when it takes longer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's good to know! Do you know if it's possible to have muliple versions of the same app within the Google private channel? Sometimes it would be good for testers to "downgrade" to an older build to verify something.

Comment: I don't believe so, when you upload a new version - which has to have a higher version number - the previous version gets invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about setting up a private android repository (e.q f-droid), but unfortunately I could not find anything in the documentation about securing the android repository - I want it to be protected somehow (key, password...).

While perhaps not in the docs, F-Droid does support HTTP Authentication on its repositories. For example, if using Apache you can add a relevant .htpasswd and .htaccess file in the webroot. This will result in the webserver sending back a 401 and asking the client to authenticate. F-Droid responds by prompting with a username/password dialog.